# Why does my php script terminate using nohup via PHP CLI

Tags: php, command-line-interface, nohup

This is more a question about nohup than my PHP script although I will include code for you guys to see. I am using a script what is designed to never end, meaning script termination should never take place. In an ideal world the script would run forever. This is achieved with `<?php while (true) {} ?>` which I am led to believe is the correct way of doing this?

However I am finding my script is terminating for reasons unknown every few days. The longest the script has run for is 4 days. I am left baffled and unable to reproduce test case scenarios without the aid of having the output from the process at the time of termination. Does nohup allow you to see what happens when the process terminates?

I can see the process running when I do ps aux and once the script has finished execution it disappears from the ps aux list, suggesting that the problem is with the she'll environment the script is run in rather than any portion of my code?

Can anybody help. Any debugging tools for this would be appreciated.

EDIT: I am looking for tools to debug this scenario any help appreciated.

Comment: is this run locally? shared host? vps?

Comment: This was run from a hp proliant g5 server that runs my local development environment, always turned on and designed to be a copy of a production server it seemed perfect to test the scenario of running a php cli script with no termination. (the script itself is actually an irc bot) - i have since bought a vps to run the shell from and am hoping this could even fix the problem?

Comment: There are no errors before the process is terminated?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to establish, what errors are there before execution finishes. Is there no way to debug this with nohup?

Comment: I just wanted to report 6 days of uptime with the new shell environment, no downtime yet.

Comment: OK so the longest uptime was 10days on the new environment

Comment: What logging can you do? Does your script have a signal handler so you could debug what signal is terminating it?

Comment: These are all questions i need answers too,,,.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was with MySQL. MySQL needed to be configured not to die after a long session. (or re-establish periodically)

Use `show variables like 'wait_timeout';` to see what your setup is configured for.